# Java: Inserting node at the end of a LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am currently learning Java and data structures, and I am trying to use insertion to insert the values in a double array to a LinkedList by only inserting each element at the end of the list. I've seen many samples online but the structure I am working with is different from what I've seen which is throwing me off and I tried implementing it in the same way. I have three Java files in the same folder: `Project.java`, `LinkedNode.java`, `WA7_List.java`.

`Project.java`

```
public class Project{

     public static void main(String[], args) {
     double[] all_inserts = [0.76697, 0.08368, 0.37785, 0.07386, 0.77287]
     }

     WA7_List linked_list = new WA7_List(M); // M is an int variable used later but can be ignored for this post.
     for (int i=0; i<all_inserts.length; i++)
        {
            linked_list.add_simple(all_inserts[i]);
        }
}
```

`LinkedNode.java`

```
public class LinkedNode {
    public LinkedNode next;
    public double item;

    public LinkedNode(LinkedNode next, double item) {
        this.next = next;
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

`WA7_List`

```
public class WA7_List {
    private LinkedNode first_node;
    private LinkedNode last_node;
    private LinkedNode[] shortcuts;
    private int count_shortcuts;
    private int count_nodes;
    private int M;

    public WA7_List(int M) {
        this.first_node = null;
        this.last_node = null;
        this.shortcuts = null;
        this.count_nodes = 0;
        this.count_shortcuts = 0;
        this.M = M;
    }

    public void add_simple(double item) {
        LinkedNode newNode = new LinkedNode(null, item);
        if (first_node==null)
        {
            first_node=newNode;
            count_nodes+=1;
        }
        last_node = first_node;
        while (null != last_node.next)
        {
            last_node = last_node.next;
        }
        last_node.next = newNode;
    }

     // There are more methods after but just focused on this first method.
}
```

Currently, the code is stuck in a forever loop because of the while loop in the add_simple method. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Do you realy need last_node and first_node? You could succeed by use only first_node.

Comment: If  you execute`firstNode = newNode` you’re done. Don’t proceed to the loop below in that case. You are creating a data loop.

Comment: @Grim I assume I dont really need it for this method, it was part of the skeleton code and was approaching it where the last_node would keep track of most recent insertion because the linkedlist should be in the same order as all_inserts.

Comment: Actually you shouldn’t have the loop at all. The idea is to maintain `lastNode` such that it always refers to the most recently added entry, so that you don’t have to loop at all.

Comment: @user207421 Ill have to read up some more on how this way works. The skeleton code had the all those variables in the constructor of `WA7_List` so I was thinking that I had to keep track of the `first_node` and `last_node` which I assume would be the last element inserted into the linked list. But correct me if im wrong!

Comment: Learn to debug. Go through the code, and act like the computer does - do exactly what it says. Usually you find the problem in your logic. If you fail at this job, run the program, and use a debugger to crosscheck what you think will happen with what actually happens (or use a boatload of System.out statements). You will soon find the problem (hint: if `first_node` is `null`, you _also_ run the code to set `last_node.next` to... itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Read comments for explanation.

```
public void add_simple(double item) {
    LinkedNode newNode = new LinkedNode(null, item);
    if (first_node == null) {
        first_node = newNode;// init first element
        last_node = newNode;// if first_node==null, the last_node is null too
        count_nodes += 1;
        return; //do nothing else if first element
    }
    last_node.next = newNode;// link new element to last element in list
    last_node = newNode; // item now is the last element
    count_nodes += 1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
public void add_simple(double item) {
    LinkedNode newNode = new LinkedNode(null, item);
    if (first_node == null) { // if list is empty and count_nodes is 0
        first_node = newNode; // we set the first node only on first insert
    } else {
        // list is not empty what automatically means we must have a last node
        last_node.next = newNode; // the new is the next of the last node
    }
    count_nodes ++;
    last_node = newNode; //always: the new is the last
}
```

Comment: You could add `synchronized` between `public` and `void` to surprise your teacher.

Comment: Oh I would love to try that, but this professor would try to fail me in this class for changing his skeleton code. Ha!

Comment: @rzan1 the skeleton code remains untouched. Oh you mean the synchronized-thing? yea, correcting the teacher is a very bad and offensive thing, even if it is professional.

Comment: Grim you should not do people’s homework for them. You should tell them how to do it, not show it. Unless you get the course credit yourself ;-)

Comment: I've tried what you have written and it seems to compile and run without errors. When I have `WA7_List linked_list = new WA7_List(M);`, does this create a linked list or would I have to create and add to a `LinkedList<WA7_List> `? That also throws me off a bit because at first I tried something like `LinkedList<WA7_List>  linked_list = new LinkedList<>();` but no one online seems to be doing that.

Comment: @user207421 yea, I am a baddie.

Comment: @rzan1 `LinkedList` is a already-working solution of your task and a library-class you should not use in the task I guess.

Comment: By the way, LinkedList have this `add_simple` method: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/1799ffeaa9baa7d703c7acc8d8738211694f946e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L152 what is suprisingly similar to my code.